# Can the Q of a loop antenna be changed?

Tags: antenna, antenna-theory

Can the Q of a loop antenna be changed?
If so what are some common techniques?  (Formulae appreciated).

Comment: Hi! Welcome here :) . As on any other SE site, we do appreciate very much when askers explain what they've researched so far, so that we don't tell them things that they already know. So, have you researched how the Q of a loop antenna "happens"? If so, what were your thoughts on changing it? What problems did you see, and what *exactly* do you need info on :)?

Comment: There are many types of loop antennas. Based on the question, you mean a small loop HF antenna of a meter or two in diameter?

Comment: The antenna is composed of multiple loops about 4 cm in diameter.  It is for an rfid tag at 13 MHZ

Comment: @monzie Thanks for that info. Why do you want to change the Q?

Comment: I am trying to decrease the system sensitivity to detuning by nearby metallic objects.

Comment: I'm not even sure that what you're describing is technically an antenna (although it's usually called antenna, for sure); it's more of the secondary side of an air-core transformer (there's a magnetic field between reader and tag, but the coil's purpose is not to extract power or radiate power in shape of an *electromagnetic wave*) . So, not even sure it *has* a Q; can you point us to some kind of description of the loop?

Comment: Also, if this really is about RFID, I'd argue it's very specific to a field of electrical engineering that is neither *amateur radio* nor *radio theory in general (as applicable esp. to ham radio)*, so I think it would find much better answers on electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: oh, by the way, the "sensitivity in presence of metal objects" is hardly something that the receiving coil has much influence on at these wavelengths. Unless "nearby" means "between the receiver and a transmitter multiple wavelengths away, and at a size at least half a wavelength", and wavelength at 13 MHz is more than 20 m...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An RF tag system is designed to function in the near field of the antennas. The frequencies involved are in the 13 MHz range and the antennas used in these applications are defined as electrically short antennas (<0.1 $\lambda$).

The near field region of the reader antenna has reactive, evanescent currents that easily couple to nearby conducting materials. It is this phenomenon that the passive tag uses to easily harvest energy via its antenna in order to send its response. Any reduction of near field currents or near field distance will result in a shortened read range due to insufficient coupling in order to power the tag.

The OP specifically asked about altering the Q of the antenna system. This can be done by altering the physical aperture of the antenna or by the matching network.

It is important to understand that the Q of the antenna system determines its bandwidth. If the Q become too high, the narrower bandwidth may not allow proper reading of the tag. As the Q is lower through its matching network, the read range will be reduced.

You can alter the Q in an existing configuration by changing the value of the resistor in the matching network of the reader. This will also require adjustment of the other matching elements. As the resistance increases, the Q of the antenna system increases and vice versa. Removing the resistor entirely will maximize the Q for a given antenna. Since the resistor effectively dissipates power in order to lower the Q, the higher the value of the resistor, the greater the currents in the near field of the antenna and vice versa.

The mathematical approach to analyzing the matching network is an exercise in simple parallel/series reduction to determine the effect of the dissipative effect of the resistor. A blanket formula is not possible due to the various topologies of matching networks.